# Please explain the first argument to the `scrapy crawl` command

Tags: python, scrapy

In [the scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) we see the project command `crawl` being run:

```
scrapy crawl quotes
```

and I wonder about the argument `quotes` because [earlier in the tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider) the spider was named `quotes_spider.py`.

Comment: And you gave that spider `name = "quotes"`. *"`name`: identifies the Spider. It must be unique within a project..."* *"This command runs the spider with name `quotes` that we’ve just added"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
```

After 'scrapy crawl quotes' is listed in the documentation, the next line says this.

> This command runs the spider with name quotes that we’ve just added,
>   that will send some requests for the quotes.toscrape.com domain

The name of the spider was defined name="quotes" in the class shown above.

You are now running that spider class, so the argument is the name of the spider you want to run.